# Symfony 2 - show only one entity from OneToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to display the min date from a group of entities in a relationship. Eg. I have User and Contracts -> the User has many Contracts, but I need to display the minimum date from contracts.

Here is the code:

```php
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comp\ContractBundle\Entity\Contract", mappedBy="user_id")
* @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
*
*/
private $contracts;
}

class Contract
{
/**
 * @var string $datastart
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datastart", type="datetime")
 */
private $datastart;

/**
 * @var string $dataend
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dataend", type="datetime")
 */
private $dataend;

/**
 * @var integer $user_id
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comp\AuthBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user_id;
}

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){

   #... other data
   $builder->add('contracts','collection', array(
                'type' => new ContractType()
            ) ); 
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'User';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' =>  'Comp\AuthBundle\Entity\User',
    );
}
}
```

And the ContractType:

```php
class ContractType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('name','text');
    $builder->add('datastart','datetime');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'Contract';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' =>  'Comp\ContractBundle\Entity\Contract',
    );
}
}
```

The problem is, I get each Entity related to the User Entity - I just need to fetch one. If you know any good example - it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Change **contracts** field type from **collection** to **entity**, and google for [**query_builder** attribute of entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder).

In that attribute you can pass a closure (returning QueryBuilder) or QueryBuilder itself, in which you can retrieve specific records from given relationship.